# Add place google api

Tags: ios, addition, google-places-api

I would like to add a location to google data base using Google API place action. For the same they are providing the api which is given below.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere. 
But when i tried using the same in iPhone objective C i get the error REUEST_DENIED. I have tried using server api key as mentioned in the tutorial.Can any one please help me to solve this out?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is currently impossible to do this via API.
The process is so complicated and secured like this below
http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Places-to-Google-Maps
which is very unlikely that an API is opened for this currently